# Applying scale and rotation making mesh disturb

Tags: mesh

I have a normal cube and added subsurface and displace modifier. In the below gif file its notice when press ctrl+A and applied rotation & scale the mesh get disturb and its no more normal shape. Any suggestion or help why its behaving. Thanks
["https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2895" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2895/)
[image]

Comment: Displacement takes object rotation and scale into consideration, if you change or apply those transforms displacement will naturally change. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos im trying to make dupliframes and make the mesh along the curve so i want to apply rotation and scale. Is there any other way